# Using Polymer paper-elements instead of standard elements loads super slowly

Tags: polymer

I wanted to try using [polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/) as I'm really excited about Material Design and this seemed a great way to embrace that design philosophy (as well as some other aspects of it, like data binding) so I decided to start swapping in polymer elements for the html ones.

The problem is that after changing inputs, checkboxes, and dropdowns to paper-inputs, paper-checkboxes, and paper-dropdown-menus, the page loads freaking slowly. I'm talking a 1-1.5s load rocketing up to ~9s load times.

Is this normal? Is there any way this can be fixed?

It seems that the polymer demo app [topeka](http://www.polymer-project.org/apps/topeka/) loads very quickly, so what steps do I need to take ot make it faster?

Imports:

```
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html" />
```

Paper uses:

```
                    <td>
                            <paper-icon-button class="mini" icon="clear"></paper-icon-button>
                            <paper-input value="<?=ucwords($item['name']) ?>" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>Name" width="150px"  />
                            </paper-input>
                        </td>

                    <td>
                        <paper-dropdown-menu selected="<?=$item['catName'] ?>" valueattr="label">
                        <?php

                            foreach ($select_options as $op) {
                                ?>
                                <paper-item label="<?=$op ?>"></paper-item>
                                <?php
                            }
                        ?>
                        </paper-dropdown-menu>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                            <paper-input multiline maxrows="3" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>Description" value="<?=$item['description'] ?>" layout vertical >
                            </paper-input>
                        </td>
                        <td><paper-input type="number" label="Regular" floatingLabel="true" value="<?=$item['price'] ?>" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>Price" ></paper-input>
                            <br /><br />
                            <paper-input type="number" label="Sale" floatingLabel="true" value="<?=$item['sale_price'] ?>" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>SalePrice" ></paper-input>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <paper-checkbox data-tip="On Sale" type="checkbox" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>OnSale" <?=$saleChecked ?>></paper-checkbox>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <paper-checkbox data-tip="Enabled" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>Enabled"  <?=$checked ?> />  
                        </td>
                        <td><paper-checkbox data-tip="In Stock" id="prod<?=$prodID ?>InStock"  <?=$stockChecked ?>  /></td>
                        <td>
                            <paper-button raisedButton class="colored" onclick="getVals(<?=$prodID ?>)">Update</paper-button>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code of what you did? - So that we can see if there's anything in it that's slowing things down. I suspect the culprit is somewhere in there...

Comment: @SFLee Added the code. It's literally just imports and replacing native HTML elements with the paper elements

Comment: It looks like you're rendering a table. How many items are in your table?

Comment: @robdodson Hmm good point. I have something like 50 elements in the table, and when I limited it to 10 it did load much more quickly. However, scalability is definitely desirable and it seems a shame to limit polymer to small use-cases

Comment: One thing to note is that the paper-* elements were really created to push the browser in terms of animation and shadows. As a result, they can be expensive to construct and and should probably be used judiciously at this point. Longer term we're trying to pare these down so they're less expensive. Tables are also historically slow to do layout, so combining the two might be hurting you. It'd be interesting to see the layout done with divs as one potential area of optimization.

Comment: @robdodson Interesting. I'll try switching over to divs and comparing the results

Answer (score 1):

Try [`vulcanizing` your imports](https://github.com/polymer/vulcanize) into a bundle using the `--csp --inline` flags. That should cut down on the number of requests and speed up the load time significantly.

Comment: So I did try vulcanizing them earlier (ran into issues because it's  a php file, but then refactored the imports into a separate file and vulcanized that) but it barely helped - 7s loads instead of 8.5-9.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this in?

Comment: Chrome. Firefox freezes and takes even longer. IE takes easily twice as long as Chrome